# What is time complexity of this algorithm ? (inner loop changes due to outer loop)

Tags: algorithm

```
Algorithm(n):
   i = 1 , k = 0
   while i <= n {

    for (j = 1  to n/i){
        k = k+1
       }
    i = i * 2
   }
```

I understand outer loop works logn, i'm not sure but for inner loop it is working like n/i + n/i/2 .. n/i/2^n  . (it is not logn because We are updating i in outer loop)

i don't know how to combine them, because time complexity of inner loop changes at every loop.

Can anyone help me about this? What is the time complexity

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601419/time-complexity-for-dependant-nested-for-loop?rq=1), although your two algorithms are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i did some maths on this and it gave me the answer.

lets say n %2 = 0 and lets say 2^x = n and x is int.

for i = 1 -> n/i

for i = 2 -> n/2i

for i = 4 -> n/4i

for i = n -> n/ni

n/i ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + .. + 1/n)  and  [1/2 + 1/4 ... 1/2^n] --> 1

n * 2/i --> n>i so the answer is O(n)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` in the outer loop takes on the values

```
i = 1, 2, 4, 8, ... X
```

where `X` is the smallest power of `2` larger than `n` (so `X` <= `2n`).

For example, when `n = 32`:

```
i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64.
```

Your inner loop runs `n/i` times (this might be rounded up or down, which is inconsequential here).

For example, when `n = 32`, the inner loop will run:

```
32/1 + 32/2 + 32/4 + 32/8 + 32/16 + 32/32 + 32/64
=
32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 0
= 63 times
```

If you reverse the sum, you get the sum of all powers of `2` less than or equal to `n`, which is `Theta(n)` (at most `2n`).

Answer (score -1):

the answer is O(n).
if you start checking loops you will get it easily